# bug in tag alias?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, tags

Today I tried to ask a question with tag **regex** and got rejected with:

```
Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:

    Creating the new tag [regular-expressions] is not allowed since the tag [regular-expression] already exists. If you think this new tag should be allowed, raise it on meta.
```

I didn't type "regular-expressions" so I assumed that "regex" was aliased to it, before it became outdated/superceded by "regular-expression".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [regular-expressions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regular-expressions) tag actually does exist, but something's wrong; I can't get to its synonym list (but I see the [regex](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regex) synonym in the master list), and your new question tried to create it, so apparently some parts of the system don't see it. I'm going to wait for a dev to look at this before I fix the synonym and merge them

Answer (score 0):

Can't repro: tagging with [regex](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regex) now automatically retags with [regular-expression](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regular-expression) (singular). [regular-expressions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regular-expressions) is an unused tag (a part from one test I made that will go away very soon).